# Optaplanner : how to manage a PlanningVariable for a list?

Tags: optaplanner

I started my problem from MeetingScheduling example.

I have Participants in groups and each participant have a list of slots where he is unavailable:

```
public class Participant {
    private Group group;
    private List<Slot> unavailabilityList;
}
```

I do meetings between Groups, for each meeting, the planner must assign:
- a time slot
- for each Group, an available Participant for this selected slot

```
@PlanningEntity()
public class Meeting {
    private List<Group> groupList;

    /** @PlanningVariable ? */
    private List<Participant> participantList;

    private Slot slot;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"slotRange"}, nullable = true)
    public Slot getSlot() {
        return slot;
    }
}
```

The goal is to maximize assigned meetings number.

The list of participants on meeting need to be a planning variable.
I read in other questions on stackOverflow that it is not possible to have PlanningVariable on List.

How can I manage this problem?

Comment: See Ondrej's answer, but also [read this guide](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2016/10/26/DomainModelingGuide.html) to understand modeling better.

Answer (score 2):

Create a MeetingAssignment class, where you'll assign a single Participant to a Meeting. And then let the Meeting only have the group list and the room.

Brief UML diagram:

[image: Brief UML diagram]

Comment: I can not assign a participant to a meeting. I need to maximize meetings number by letting the planner assign available participant for each group of a meeting.

Comment: Create N MeetingAssignments for every Meeting (where N = the number of groups needed to attend a meeting). Then let OptaPlanner assign a Person of the group to a MeetingAssignment.

Comment: In that case, Meeting and MeetingAssignment are both PlanningEntity ? Sorry i'm a noob in OptaPlanner. It's a powerfull tool, but hard for a debutant.

Comment: or we can have a @PlanningVariable not in a planningEntity class ?

Comment: Yes, I think both should be planning entities. Not sure it is exactly what you want to do in practice, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks oskopek and Geoffrey. I did not have time to look at that because my client's priorities changed suddenly! :)