# Constraint joins for list based planning variables

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am just starting out with OptaPlanner and have a question about building constraints against lists planning variables.

Now I know list planning variables are not supported, but I have been looking at the following post which suggests using an intermediate object that allows a planning entity to be mapped to a list of planning variables: [Optaplanner : how to manage a PlanningVariable for a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978981/optaplanner-how-to-manage-a-planningvariable-for-a-list/)

If I was to following that pattern, my question is, how to perform a join in a constraint to get the left and right hand planning variables. So, for example, if I take the time table example as its the one I have looked at and modify it allow for a list of rooms, for example...

[image]

...would look something like the following:

[image]

Moving onto the constraints, when the constraint looks for a unique pair of lessons, I also want to be able to effectively flatten the list of rooms for each pair of lessons, so I can pass the following parameters into my filter. The behaviour I am looking for is to get each unique pair of rooms across each unique pair of lessons.

For example, something like the following:

```
return factory
    .fromUniquePair(Lesson.class)
    .join(RoomGroup.class)
    ...
    .filter((lhLesson, rhLesson, lhRoom, rhRoom) -> {...})
    ...
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: At the moment, I see no other way than writing a custom collector.
That said, if you know how to list non-unique pairs, distinct() will fix the uniqueness aspect for you.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a try and will post up here what I find.